# How to clear primary key id generator in eloquent/mysql?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel 5.7 / mysql 5.7 app using eloquent I can clear rows in table using model :

```
Model::truncate();
```

But can I to clear primary key id generator, so first row would have value for id=1 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, clearing all rows in a table then once a new first record is inserted it becomes `id = 1` of the table?

Comment: Yes, on new insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model::truncate()` uses 'TRUNCATE' function of MySQL so it resets your 'auto_increment' counter as well.

Read more about 'TRUNCATE' here [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html)

So basically the new insert will start from 1 if the primary key field of the table was made `Auto Increment`